# What is that makes us slow down in water?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, fluid-statics

I know this may sound very weird, but I'm curious on what makes the water be like water? Like why, when we get into a pool, we are like in a "lower gravity" pull? All our movements are slowed down in water in comparison to air? I very much know it is a strange question, but I've really never thought of it this way, I've always assumed water is like that, but never actually started to think why we move like that underwater.

I'm guessing, it has to do with the properties of the water, but if someone can shed some more light on this, I'd appreciate it?

Comment: Water is more dense than air, so the buoyant force of water is greater. The buoyant force opposes the force of gravity.

Comment: Search for buoyancy and viscosity. They give any liquid the properties you just described.

Comment: Density and viscosity, but the bigger reason is density. Water is about 1000x as dense as air.   Interestingly, very tiny insects (eg fairyfly) move through air more like fish moving through water.  Their very small mass makes even air more difficult to push against

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, water is many times denser than air. To move through it, you have to set it into motion to push it out of your way and since it has significant mass, this requires significant push.

In addition, water has much more viscosity (think: "goopiness") than air does. This means that as you move through it, it applies a drag force to you which resists your motion, and that goopiness will bring you to a stop if you are coasting through it.

Finally, any object less dense than water will float in it when immersed (or, if it is more dense than water, it will sink instead). Since you are slightly less dense than pure water, you will float.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to move your arm in water you have accelerate some of the surrounding water as well as your arm. So, even in the absence of friction or buoyancy, you arm has a greater *inertial mass* (the $m$ in $F=ma$) and thus a given force applied by your muscles takes longer to get your arm moving. See the wikipedia article on [added mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Added_mass).